# format of read file in fortran

Tags: fortran90

What should be the read format of the of following dataset in fortran. there are 6 spaces between column 1 and 2 with no space of column 1 from margin.

```
1911.01.01     2.42873702403226
1911.01.02     3.5057043827303
1911.01.03     2.73602527398387
1911.01.04     6.07213767208333
1911.01.05     6.94818901068145
1911.01.06     3.66986589769583
1911.01.07     1.94565994542339
1911.01.08     2.39384275272177
1911.01.09     3.05526130775417
1911.01.10     2.69990836499194
1911.01.11     6.08406263835833
1911.01.12     7.34200241064516
1911.01.13     2.42873702403226
1911.01.14     3.5057043827303
1911.01.15     2.73602527398387
1911.01.16     6.07213767208333
1911.01.17     6.94818901068145
1911.01.18     3.66986589769583
1911.01.19     1.94565994542339
1911.01.20     2.39384275272177
1911.01.21     3.05526130775417
1911.01.22     2.69990836499194
1911.01.23     6.08406263835833
1911.01.24     7.34200241064516
1911.01.25     2.42873702403226
1911.01.26     3.5057043827303
1911.01.27     2.73602527398387
1911.01.28     6.07213767208333
1911.01.29     6.94818901068145
1911.01.30     3.66986589769583
1911.01.31     1.94565994542339
```

I tried.....
format `(i4,i2,i2,6x,d9.14)`

but it didnt work

thanks in advance

elisa

Answer (score 0):

So try

```
(i4,a1,i2,a1,i2,6x,d16.14)
```

I think you've made two mistakes:

1. Not accounting for the `.` characters in the dates, I don't think that they will automatically be treated as field separators (as `,` or spaces would be). Obviously you'll want to ignore them.
2. In your `d` edit descriptor the number of decimal digits, that is the number after the `.` ought to be no greater than the total field width, *ie* the number before the `.`.

Comment: thankyou very much for your reply. i am extremly greatful. But it still doesnot read the data file and the problem seems to be the same of . character in date. anyother suggestion, if you could??

Comment: You've made a third mistake -- count the spaces between the day number and the start of your real number, count them more carefully than I did when I first a.nswered and more carefully than when you posted the question